# Prevent the building of static libraries when building glibc

Tags: gcc, makefile, glibc

I am cross-compiling glibc to use in a custom Linux system. I only need shared glibc libraries, so I am trying to prevent glibc from building static libs, like "libc.a". I have tried using the "--disable-static" flag, but that does not seem to work.

My current configure command:

```
../configure \
  CFLAGS="-O2" \
  --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf \
  --prefix= \
  --includedir=/usr/include \
  --libexecdir=/usr/libexec \
  --datarootdir=/tmp \
  --localstatedir=/tmp \
  --with-__thread \
  --with-tls \
  --with-fp \
  --with-headers=/opt/sysroot/usr/include \
  --without-cvs \
  --without-gd \
  --enable-kernel=3.18.0 \
  --enable-stack-protector=strong \
  --enable-shared \
  --enable-add-ons=no \
  --enable-obsolete-rpc \
  --disable-profile \
  --disable-debug \
  --disable-sanity-checks \
  --disable-static \
  --disable-werror
```

Answer (score 0):

As this wouldn't get you any wins w.r.t. build time (dumpnig a bunch of files into a `.a` file and creating an index should be nothing compared to linking them into a shared library), I assume what you are after is a convenient way to install just the parts you need.

I haven't tried it myself, but doesn't `make install-no-libc.a` do what you want?

Comment: Well, libc.a is just one example. There are many static files. Seems weird that I would have to define every single file I don't want instead of just turning off building of static files and then a simple "make install". This works for most other programs, so why not for glibc?